# Xpath - how to exclude element's child?

Tags: html, xpath

I have the following html code:

```
<div class="form-field checkbox-terms_of_services">
    <input id="register-terms_of_services" type="checkbox" class="input-block checkbox">
    <label for="register-terms_of_services"> 
    </label
</div>
```

[image]

I'm trying to click on the checkbox.

I tried this xpath:
//input[@class='input-block checkbox']

but it's ignore it.

so I took the div above, but it's clicking on the link of terms of services.
How can I build an XPATH that will take the div element and exclude the label element?

Comment: I don't understand; XPath can't "click" so what are you talking about?

Comment: better use the id attribute than the class one `//input[@id="register-terms_of_services"]`

Comment: @Fravadona the element of this xpath do nothing if I code ```element.click();```
@LMC the website recognize the xpath, but while running the click doesn't happened. if I use the div above, it's clicking on the link of terms of service. I try to find a way to ignore this link and click on the checkbox. if there is such a way.

Comment: @chanak you can add the `checked` attribute to the input checkbox element

Comment: waht do you mean with `link of terms of services.`?

Answer (score 0):

I found a working solution:

```
if(!element.isSelected()) {
            element.sendKeys(Keys.SPACE);
        }
```

In this way the checkbox is correctly selected